# Removing key from session state

Tags: f#, suave

(*Noting that my total experience with Suave and back-end web-development in general can be measured in days and counted on one hand*)

As part of my project, whenever a user successfully signs in a unique GUID is created and stored within the session state (using a `SessionID` key). Subsequent requests from that same user pass in that same GUID (from the session state) where it is looked up from a map held in server memory in order to confirm authority.

This part works perfectly using the approach from the Suave [documentation](https://suave.io/sessions.html). To clarify, my routing path uses `statefulForSession` along with `setSessionValue` and `getSessionValue` as defined in the documentation to set and read the `SessionID` key referred to above.

When a user logs-out or there has not been any activity for a certain period of time, the GUID will be removed from the server held map above. **Is it possible to remove a key (`SessionID`) from the session state?** ie... **Is there a possible definition for a `removeSessionValue`?**

Given the underlying `StateStore` object only exposes `set` and `get`, it makes me wonder whether what I'm asking is (somewhat) non-sensical or whether there is some other mechanism I should be using.

From the Suave source code, I'm aware that the session state (which is held in a string -> object map) is ultimately serialised and encrypted within a cookie called `st`.

---

**Update 2021-11-08:**

A [pull request](https://github.com/SuaveIO/suave/pull/758) has since been submitted where an `unset` method is exposed by the `StateStore` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're asking for seems reasonable, but I don't think there's a clean way to do it given the current `StateStore` API. That said, you can hack the low-level cookie state as follows:

```ml
let removeSessionValue (key : string) : WebPart =
    context (fun ctx ->
        let cookieState =
            {
                serverKey      = ctx.runtime.serverKey
                cookieName     = StateCookie
                userStateKey   = StateStoreType
                relativeExpiry = Session
                secure         = false
            }
        updateCookies cookieState (function
            | None ->
                Map.empty
                    |> ctx.runtime.cookieSerialiser.serialise

            | Some data ->
                try
                    let m = ctx.runtime.cookieSerialiser.deserialise data
                    m
                    |> Map.remove key   // this is where we remove the key
                    |> ctx.runtime.cookieSerialiser.serialise
                with ex ->
                    Map.empty
                    |> ctx.runtime.cookieSerialiser.serialise))
```

I copied most of this from the [Suave source code](https://github.com/SuaveIO/suave/blob/052a696e160f38fe06e8169757c6566bb9502e5d/src/Suave/State.fs#L24) and tried it quickly to make sure it works, but I can't guarantee its correctness.

Comment: Thank you for this! With your proposed solution, it looks as though if the key cannot be found, the entirety of the session state is emptied. **I'm guessing the `try` block is to catch any errors arising on deserialisation or when removing the key as well?** I've proposed a slight variation [here](https://gist.github.com/Rich-F-G-Mills/71d8051c7efad6bf46b30dfa8fe28ff6). **Does that seem reasonable?**

Comment: In your link it does not look like the `with` expression will ever be entered due to your  `m |> Map.containsKey key` test (BTW, I made the expression more idiomatic F# here but that is not substantive to this point). Also consider `Map.tryFindKey` which returns an Option. Either way looks like you can avoid exception handling which is to be preferred. Also it is better to provide the code here rather than elsewhere as it is easier for us all to follow the thread of discussion.

Comment: @MartinFreedman Thank you for taking a look. The `try` block is needed because it _looks_ as though `deserialise` can fail. This is based on the definition of `get` located [here](https://github.com/SuaveIO/suave/blob/57d69e39e67a5b1a1c60b7c015c698a1901a9420/src/Suave/State.fs#L97). And I totally agree... I could have written that in a more idiomatic way. Also... Point taken regarding showing code here although I'm not sure how I could have done that. **By possibly updating my original question above?** To have included in a comment would have taken too much space.

Comment: @RMills330 `Map.remove` [doesn't raise an exception if the element is not present](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-collections-mapmodule.html#remove), so a missing key isn't going to empty the session state. I believe the exception handler is only needed in the case where the map couldn't be deserialized from the cookie. This logic was copied from the Suave source code.

Comment: @RMIlls330. I think updating the question with an Update section is the preferred resolution, or, you could submit your own answer, even if you approve another one.

Comment: @brianberns Had I properly read the `Map` documentation, I'd have known better! Thank you for confirming.

Comment: @MartinFreedman Understood. Thank you for letting me know.